# How to remove the WooCommerce Product->Category thumbnail from admin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I've successfully removed the thumbnail from the Admin->Products

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns`, 'myRemoveProductColumns' );
function myRemoveProductColumns( $columns)
{    
    unset( $columns['thumb'] );
    return $columns;
}
```

but can't seem to remove that same column from the Product->Categories.

I tried:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_columns`, 'myRemoveProductCategoryColumns' );
function myRemoveProductCategoryColumns( $columns)
{    
    unset( $columns['thumb'] );
    return $columns;
}
```

to no avail. Any thoughts? Have I missed something here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add lower priority to your action, then it should work. (*At least it worked on my local WP sandbox*)

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_columns', 'myRemoveProductCategoryColumns', 99 );
```